# Odd justification for ggplot2 axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am encountering a strange axis text alignment problem, as can be seen in the graphic below (you might need to zoom in on the image to see the problem):

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis text is drawn far below the ticks, the y-axis text is far to the left of the ticks, and the ticks themselves are all over the place... What might be causing this behavior, and (perhaps more importantly) what can be done to avoid this? Code included below, as well as massive dput().

```
ZP6 <- ggplot(TestData,
 aes(x = Mean, y = Value))
ZP6 <- ZP6 + geom_point()
ZP6 <- ZP6 + geom_errorbarh(aes(x = Mean, xmin = Mean - ZMult * SE,
 xmax = Mean + ZMult* SE, height = 0), size = I(1/3))
ZP6 <- ZP6 + facet_grid(Category ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free")
ZP6 <- ZP6 + scale_x_continuous("Principal Evaluative Dimension", breaks = c(-1, 0, 1)/2)
ZP6 <- ZP6 + scale_y_discrete(name = "")
ZP6 <- ZP6 + opts(title = "Mean Ideology by Characteristic")
print(ZP6)
```

dput() of TestData can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83576/TestData%20dput%28%29.txt).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: were you using another package in addition to ggplot2? When I try to dget() I get the error "Error in structure(list(Category = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L,  : 
  object 'Category' not found"

Comment: I was, but I don't know how it could be causing that error. I have uploaded a CSV that constitutes TestData here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83576/Stack%20Overflow%20Data.csv

Comment: I _knew_ I'd read about this. It's a [bug](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/221) that I believe is fixed in the dev version.

Comment: I suppose this gives me incentive to learn how to install the dev version. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, this behavior is a [bug](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/221) in version 0.8.9 that has been fixed in the new version (0.9.0).