# odd formatting for categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Odd justification for ggplot2 axis text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085269/odd-justification-for-ggplot2-axis-text)

I am rather new to ggplot, but have some decent experience with R and lattice graphics.

I am trying to reproduce a graphic found on Prof. Whickham's ggplot2 website (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html) and am having trouble with my tick label justificaiton.  The plot below shows the output of the following code:

```
    qplot(cty, model, data=mpg) + 
            facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free")
```

As the site is not allowing me to post an image. The description of the behavior I am seeing is as follows:  The category labels described by "model" are showing up with what looks like different spaces between the tick mark and the actual axis.  So, if the list of labels is supposed to look like this:

1. label 1 -
2. label 2 -
3. label 3 -
4. ...

it is actually looking like this:

1. label 1 -
2. \s\s\s label 2 -
3. \s\s label 3 -
4. ...

where "\s" represents the odd spacing seen, these characters are not actually shown on the plot.  The odd spacing does appear correlated to the conditioning variable "manufacturer" in the facet_grid() function.

I hope this is an adequate description.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Matt

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I found a previously posted thread.  Sorry for not seeing this earlier.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085269/odd-justification-for-ggplot2-axis-text